# What do these logs mean? Is someone attempting to hack into my server via ssh?

Tags: ssh, logging, ddos

Today I woke up to a a very large number of logs for `ssh`, and I can only assume someone is trying to gain access to my linux server.

Here are the logs

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2023-08-02 08:59:10 EEST, end at Wed 2024-01-24 08:57:36 EET. --
ian 24 08:53:49 Linux-Server sshd[372712]: Invalid user mireielle from 201.184.50.251 port 59440
ian 24 08:53:49 Linux-Server sshd[372712]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
ian 24 08:53:49 Linux-Server sshd[372712]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=201.184.50.251
ian 24 08:53:51 Linux-Server sshd[372712]: Failed password for invalid user mireielle from 201.184.50.251 port 59440 ssh2
ian 24 08:53:51 Linux-Server sshd[372712]: Received disconnect from 201.184.50.251 port 59440:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
ian 24 08:53:51 Linux-Server sshd[372712]: Disconnected from invalid user mireielle 201.184.50.251 port 59440 [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:08 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: User root from 218.92.0.29 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
ian 24 08:54:09 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.29  user=root
ian 24 08:54:11 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.92.0.29 port 41135 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:14 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.92.0.29 port 41135 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:14 Linux-Server sshd[372731]: Invalid user hawkos from 118.163.63.23 port 33902
ian 24 08:54:14 Linux-Server sshd[372731]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
ian 24 08:54:14 Linux-Server sshd[372731]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=118.163.63.23
ian 24 08:54:16 Linux-Server sshd[372731]: Failed password for invalid user hawkos from 118.163.63.23 port 33902 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:16 Linux-Server sshd[372731]: Received disconnect from 118.163.63.23 port 33902:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:16 Linux-Server sshd[372731]: Disconnected from invalid user hawkos 118.163.63.23 port 33902 [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:18 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.92.0.29 port 41135 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:20 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.29 port 41135:11:  [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:20 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: Disconnected from invalid user root 218.92.0.29 port 41135 [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:20 Linux-Server sshd[372726]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.29  user=root
ian 24 08:54:50 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: User root from 218.92.0.29 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
ian 24 08:54:50 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.29  user=root
ian 24 08:54:52 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.92.0.29 port 23264 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:54 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.92.0.29 port 23264 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:55 Linux-Server sshd[372745]: Invalid user skaret from 201.184.50.251 port 51582
ian 24 08:54:55 Linux-Server sshd[372745]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
ian 24 08:54:55 Linux-Server sshd[372745]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=201.184.50.251
ian 24 08:54:57 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: Failed password for invalid user root from 218.92.0.29 port 23264 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:57 Linux-Server sshd[372745]: Failed password for invalid user skaret from 201.184.50.251 port 51582 ssh2
ian 24 08:54:59 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.29 port 23264:11:  [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:59 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: Disconnected from invalid user root 218.92.0.29 port 23264 [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:59 Linux-Server sshd[372743]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.29  user=root
ian 24 08:54:59 Linux-Server sshd[372745]: Received disconnect from 201.184.50.251 port 51582:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
ian 24 08:54:59 Linux-Server sshd[372745]: Disconnected from invalid user skaret 201.184.50.251 port 51582 [preauth]
ian 24 08:55:13 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: User root from 180.101.88.221 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
ian 24 08:55:13 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=180.101.88.221  user=root
ian 24 08:55:15 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: Failed password for invalid user root from 180.101.88.221 port 62046 ssh2
ian 24 08:55:18 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: Failed password for invalid user root from 180.101.88.221 port 62046 ssh2
ian 24 08:55:21 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: Failed password for invalid user root from 180.101.88.221 port 62046 ssh2
ian 24 08:55:23 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: Received disconnect from 180.101.88.221 port 62046:11:  [preauth]
ian 24 08:55:23 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: Disconnected from invalid user root 180.101.88.221 port 62046 [preauth]
ian 24 08:55:23 Linux-Server sshd[372748]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=180.101.88.221  user=root
ian 24 08:56:04 Linux-Server sshd[372762]: Invalid user ubuntu from 201.184.50.251 port 43720
ian 24 08:56:04 Linux-Server sshd[372762]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
ian 24 08:56:04 Linux-Server sshd[372762]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=201.184.50.251
ian 24 08:56:06 Linux-Server sshd[372762]: Failed password for invalid user ubuntu from 201.184.50.251 port 43720 ssh2
ian 24 08:56:08 Linux-Server sshd[372762]: Received disconnect from 201.184.50.251 port 43720:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
ian 24 08:56:08 Linux-Server sshd[372762]: Disconnected from invalid user ubuntu 201.184.50.251 port 43720 [preauth]
ian 24 08:56:48 Linux-Server sshd[372771]: Invalid user alberik from 118.163.63.23 port 38078
ian 24 08:56:48 Linux-Server sshd[372771]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
ian 24 08:56:48 Linux-Server sshd[372771]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=118.163.63.23
ian 24 08:56:50 Linux-Server sshd[372771]: Failed password for invalid user alberik from 118.163.63.23 port 38078 ssh2
ian 24 08:56:51 Linux-Server sshd[372771]: Received disconnect from 118.163.63.23 port 38078:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

These are the logs for the last 5 minutes.

I traced them back to starting on `Octomber 23, 00:00:42 AM`. And they seem really fishy.

Do I have anything to worry about? I have 5 different allowed ssh users, 2 of which I contained in an SSH jail, with access only to the following folders:

```
bin  dev  etc  lib  lib64  proc  run  sbin  share  sys  tmp  usr
```

Share is just a intermediary directory to allow specific users to specific folders.

So, am I getting hacked? Is this a potential DDoS attack? What can I do?

I will be thankful for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to the internet where bots constantly try to find machines to hack into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a service to the internet you can be sure that it doesn't take long until some botnet finds it and starts trying to find security holes.

- keep your server up to date
- disable login with known usernames (`root`)
- disable password login, use public key auth only
- if you can, limit access to the service to specific IP addresses or subnets via a firewall.
- set up fail2ban to make it harder to probe your server

Comment: So, It's a botnet. And since I see It has used many different IPs, I assume I can not just block a IP. Logging it with root is disabled. I have enforced security in the ssh configuration. Hopefully, I can keep any intruders out this way. And I would like to use public key auth, but I was never able to get It to work, and for SFTP, most apps require password authentication.

Comment: I don't know if it's a botnet. The point is, if you open a service to the internet you can expect it to be constantly probed. The number of (IPv4) addresses is limited, they are all known.